# How to keep triggered div expanded while hovering?

Tags: jquery

So I have a setup where hovering over a div triggers a separate div to expand. I have it working as expected, but I’ve run into some difficulties.

**Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9rshL6hk/**

---

Two issues:

- If you quickly hover back and forth over all the Button# divs, then a queue builds up. It works fine on a per-button basis, but breaks down when quickly hovering over multiple elements.
- This one is a bit tricky to explain. Basically I’d like to move the mouse into the expanded submenu div and not have it immediately shrink. Enhanced description below.

*(Hoping to achieve: Once the mouse leaves the ‘Button 1’ div, then the ‘Submenu 1’ div will stay expanded. But it will stay expanded only as long as the mouse still hovers within the ‘Submenu 1’ div. Basically just extending the properties of the ‘Button 1’ div into the ‘Submenu 1’ so that it can remain open like you’d expect with any typical button/submenu setup.)*

---

jQuery

```
$("#button1").data("panelId", "#submenu1");
$("#button2").data("panelId", "#submenu2");
$("#button3").data("panelId", "#submenu3");

$("#button1, #button2, #button3").hover(function() {
    var first = true;
    var panelId = $(this).data("panelId");
    $(".chain").not(panelId).slideUp(function() {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            $(panelId).stop().slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
});
```

---

HTML

```
<div id="button1">Button 1</div>
<div id="button2">Button 2</div>
<div id="button3">Button 3</div>

<div id="submenu1" class="chain">Submenu 1</div>
<div id="submenu2" class="chain">Submenu 2</div>
<div id="submenu3" class="chain">Submenu 3</div>
```

---

CSS

```
#button1,#button2,#button3 {
    display:inline;
    background-color:LightBlue;
    margin:2px;
    font-size:30px;
}

.chain {display:none;}

#submenu1 {
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
#submenu2 {
    background:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
#submenu3 {
    background:orange;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Please add your html in case jsfiddle.net for whatever reason goes defunct.

Comment: Gotcha. I updated it to include the related HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**
For your 2nd Issue - **[Working Demo Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/zy11k47n/)**

Change your `hover` event to `mouseenter` as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").data("panelId", "#submenu1");
    $("#button2").data("panelId", "#submenu2");
    $("#button3").data("panelId", "#submenu3");

    $("#button1, #button2, #button3").mouseenter(function() {
        var first = true;
        var panelId = $(this).data("panelId");
        $(".chain").not(panelId).slideUp(function() {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                //alert('sdfddsfs');
                $(panelId).stop().slideToggle(400);
            }
        });
       setTimeout(function(){ // UPDATED - FOR CLEAR THE QUEUE
        //$( ".chain" ).stop(false,true);
        $( ".chain" ).finish(); // you can use either .stop() or .finish()               
       },400);
    });

    $( ".chain" ).mouseenter(function() {
            //alert('sdf');
        $(this).slideDown(400);  
    });
    $( ".chain" ).mouseout(function() {
            //alert('sdf');
        $(this).slideUp(400);  
    });
});
```

See the above code for **updated answer**.

**Updated Answer: -** use [.finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) to clear the animation queue.

Comment: I'd recommend using the newer [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  Example `$(".chain").on('mouseenter', function() { ... } );`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is an updated jsFiddle example for posterity: http://jsfiddle.net/7bLqeLy8/

Comment: Any idea of how to address the queue buildup?

Comment: @nuclearsugar - Hey , Use `.finish()` for clear the event queue in JQuery, - see the updated answer :) - Glad to help you.